# setar pagina principal com dados de um popup

Tags: popup

Bom dia.
Estou precisando de ajuda pra resolver um problema.
Tenho uma pagina A onde fica os dados do pedido que vou fazer. Na pagina a tem um campo que é o de fornecedor mas  que abri um popup B. No popup é feita uma consulta ao banco que retorna os fornecedores a partir do usuário logado. nessa lista o usuário deve escolher um fornecedor e esse fornecedor é inserido no campo na pagina A. podem ajudar?

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Seria interessante você adicionar um [mcve], assim, fica mais fácil te orientar a uma possivel solução.

Comment: Em quais linguagens está desenvolvendo?

Comment: Em java mas podendo usar javaScript